# Pulling valid data from bytestring in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-3.2

Given the following bytestring, how can I remove any characters matching \xFF, and create a list object from what's left (by splitting on removed areas)?

```
b"\x07\x00\x00\x00~\x10\x00pts/5\x00\x00/5\x00\x00user\x00\x00"
```

Desired result:

```
["~", "pts/5", "/5", "user"]
```

The above string is just an example - I'd like to remove any \x.. (non-decoded) bytes.

I'm using Python 3.2.3, and would prefer to use standard libraries only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = b"\x07\x00\x00\x00~\x10\x00pts/5\x00\x00/5\x00\x00user\x00\x00"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(rb"[^\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]+", a)
[b'~', b'pts/5', b'/5', b'user']
```

The results are still `bytes` objects. If you want the results to be strings:

```
>>> [i.decode("ascii") for i in re.findall(rb"[^\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]+", a)]
['~', 'pts/5', '/5', 'user']
```

**Explanation:**

`[^\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]+` matches one or more (`+`) characters that are *not* in the range (`[^...]`) between ASCII 0 and 31 (`\x00-\x1F`) or between ASCII 127 and 255 (`\x7f-\xff`).

Be aware that this approach only works if the "embedded texts" are ASCII. It will remove all extended alphabetic characters (like `ä`, `é`, `€` etc.) from strings encoded in an 8-bit codepage like `latin-1`, and it will effectively destroy strings encoded in `UTF-8` and other Unicode encodings because those do contain byte values between 0 and 31/127 and 255 as parts of their character codes.

Of course, you can always manually fine-tune the exact ranges you want to remove according to the example given in this answer.

Comment: I had to change re.findall(rb"pattern", a) to re.findall(b"pattern", a) to get this working on Ubuntu 12.10 (Python 3.2.3), but it did.

Some characters still get through, like \x7f and \x8e. I'm actually not sure if this bytestring is UTF-8 or not -- it's an open('/var/run/utmp', 'rb').read() in Linux.

Comment: @wroberts: Strange that Python on Ubuntu would have problems with raw strings, but yes, it does work without them (it's just generally a useful habit with regexes when there are other escape sequences that would be ambiguous otherwise, like `\b`). You can remove all characters greater than ASCII 127 as well. Will edit my answer.